# Mutating trigger in Oracle

Tags: sql, database, oracle, plsql, triggers

I create the following tables:

```
create table lessons(
id number,
name_teacher varchar2(9),
name_student varchar2(40),
start_lesson date, 
end_lesson date
);
```

I inserted the following datas:

```
insert into lessons values (001,'Peter','Thomas',to_date('2015-12-15','YYYY-MM-DD'),to_date('2015-12-22','YYYY-MM-DD'));
insert into lessons values (002,'Eli','Alice',to_date('2015-06-16','YYYY-MM-DD'),to_date('2015-06-23','YYYY-MM-DD'));
insert into lessons values (003,'Daniel','Thomas',to_date('2015-08-15','YYYY-MM-DD'),to_date('2015-08-20','YYYY-MM-DD'));
```

Data that you cant add by the trigger.

```
insert into lessons values (001,'Peter','Alice',to_date('2015-12-16','YYYY-MM-DD'),to_date('2015-12-25','YYYY-MM-DD'));
insert into lessons values (002,'Eli','Thomas',to_date('2015-06-13','YYYY-MM-DD'),to_date('2015-06-20','YYYY-MM-DD'));
```

The question is how to make a trigger that does not allow me to add students who have teachers who overlap in time, like "Peter" or "Eli".

--- My problem ---

> Oracle returns me an error of mutants tables.

Comment: Post your trigger body

Comment: insufficient information. Post the trigger code as well.

Comment: Looks like your question is really about preventing overlapping ranges, which is an old problem with no straightforward solution. It is easy enough to get around the "mutating table" error, but in a multi-user system you still need some locking to prevent two sessions entering rows that are valid in their own session but which overlap once committed.

Answer (score 1):

you neen an after insert / update Trigger that fire after the comlete insert or update and not after earch row:

```
create or replace trigger check_intersections_trg 
on 
 lessons
after insert or update
declare 
  v_res   NUMBER;
begin
  select count(*) 
  into  v_res
  from lessons l1 
  join lessons l2  on l1.name_student = l2.name_student 
                   and l1.start_lesson <= l2.end_lesson
                   and l2.start_lesson <= l1.end_lesson  
  ;
  if v_res > 0 than
   raise_application_error( -20999, 'intersection found');
  end if;
end;
/
```